# VBA for MS word

Tags: vba, ms-word

There are a lot of free sources to learn about the object model of MS Excel, but I failed to find any comprehensive source for a similar source for MS Word.

Can You suggest a free and comprehensive source for the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently learned the Word Object Model and I found the following pages most helpful.  I think that as long as you understand the Word Application (from a user perspective), all you need to do is flesh out your understanding of Word.Range and eventually Word Story Types.  And as the other posters have suggested, the Object Browser in Word's Visual Basic Editor is very convenient for browsing the available properties and methods for any particular object.

Entry point for all Word VBA.  Browse by method, object, collection, etc.:

- [Microsoft Word Visual Basic Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272078(office.11).aspx)

Helpful pages specifically about using Word's Ranges:

- [Working with Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa171380(office.11).aspx)
- [Modifying a portion of a document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211943(office.11).aspx)
- [Selection object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223084(office.11).aspx)
- [Assigning Ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211919(office.11).aspx)

An introduction to Word's Story Types:

- [Behind the Curtain: Stories in Word](http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_office_word/archive/2008/10/02/behind-the-curtain-stories-in-word.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

In the VBA editor, if you hit F2, there's an object browser that is a pretty handy reference. You can also filter it for Word-specific objects.

Comment: The object browser is really intended for VBA developers and general progammers familiar with the particular Object Model, as well as the syntax relative to that model. So, yes, it is a good reference, but it is not optimal for quickly and effectively teaching others - especially a novice in certain cases - an Object Model.

Answer (score 1):

A look into the VBA Help (along with the debugger) helped me to learn anything I needed. The help file is really comprehensive.